# Apache Axis 1: WSDL2Java - overwrite generated sources?

Tags: java, axis

When running org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java (Axis 1) against a recently changed wsdl, there is a failure because some sources already exist. Is there a way to force overwrite of existing classes? I don't see anything at http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/reference.html that can help me in this case.

I am looking for something like the -or option which can be used in the Axis 2 WSDL2Java command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to force the overwrite.  At least I can't find one in the code for the ant task so I imagine it doesn't exist.  Would using the Axis2 wsdl2java work for you with the -b and -or flags? That should generate Axis 1.x compatible code and give you access to the overwrite option that does exist in the Axis2 version of the command.